# How to have docker and npm in gitlab-ci-runner-docker

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab-ci with `docker:dind` as a service.

#### problem

I am trying in Gitlab-CI run `npm run build` followed by `docker build`.

I am able this way to build using docker in docker this way:

This is my runner `config.toml`:

```
$ cat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml 
concurrent = 4
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "developers_gitlab_school-gitlab-runner-docker"
  url = "https://school.domain.com"
  token = "cd09f40c6a4....a44751fec795e35"
  executor = "docker"
  builds_dir = "/mnt/mesos/sandbox/builds"
  cache_dir = "/mnt/mesos/sandbox/cache"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

This is an example of `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: docker:latest
# image: mcasimir/dind-node-build-runner:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker --version
  - docker login -u ${REGISTRY_USERNAME} -p ${REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${REGISTRY_URL}

stages:
  - build

# Job: Build
build_dev:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t group/mail-server/dev:${CI_JOB_ID} .
  only:
    - dev
  tags:
    - docker

build_master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t domain/mail-server:${CI_JOB_ID} .
    - docker build -t domain/mail-server:latest .
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - docker
```

1. When I use an image with docker and npm for my build [mcasimir/dind-node-build-runner:latest](https://github.com/mcasimir/dind-node-build-runner)
   I have :

   ```
   Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
   ```
2. When I use image `docker:latest`, docker-in-docker **work fine** but I still need npm.

#### question:

Because the Dockerfile of `docker:latest` is not public, and because I wasn't able to use `apt-get` from this image, I would like to know:

- If there a way to have an image that can run **docker** and **npm** in gitlab-ci ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because it is an alpine-based image, you don't have apt-get, you have `apk`. So with the default `docker:latest` just add this `apk --update add nodejs`:

```
before_script:
    - apk --update add nodejs npm
```

And you are ready with dind, nodejs and npm.

Comment: May I know  the difference between doing that and just extending the `docker:latest` with the content of [this official alpine node Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/581eebd097343c9f1c1ceb5260cd2ec770410e29/7.10/alpine/Dockerfile) ?

Comment: That alpine-node doesn't have a docker in docker install. That's the regular node base image. Does it make sense?

Comment: I have created my own Docker image using `FROM docker:latest` and I appended the content of this file. I think it does but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: That's ok if you want it. It's more robust but it's complex. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked, but I have another problem, I can't use the gitlab-ci example of ssh-agent login with alpine

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor)? Remember that apk is the equivalent of apt get

Comment: apk --update add openssh-client https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=openssh-client&arch=x86_64&repo=main

Comment: Thanks a lot. And by  any chance maybe you know how to translate `ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")` for **sh** ?

Comment: Shoud be `cat $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY | ssh-add`

Comment: cat is a bit insecure. I have opened a new question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211396/is-there-a-ssh-add-linux-alpine-one-liner

Comment: And cat is incorrect because the var is not a filename. Can you install bash for the meantime?

Answer (score -1):

If we look into the [source code](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/5a196cae40e2a0ab5050cf6d79b697e032352b24/17.05/docker-entrypoint.sh) for the docker container we can see one variable being set up: `$DOCKER_HOST`, and that's all you need just add`export DOCKER_HOST='tcp://docker:2375'` as a step in your build or set `DOCKER_HOST` as a global variable. And then you can use any image you want, not just `docker:latest`.

```
dockeralpine:
  image: alpine
  services:
   - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  tags: 
   - docker
  script:
   - apk --update add docker
   - docker ps

dockerubuntu:
  image: ubuntu
  services:
   - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  tags: 
   - docker
  script:
   - apt update
   - apt install -yqq docker.io
   - docker ps
```

Comment: I am using gitlab-ci and `.gitlab-ci.yml` does this for me. (I assume)

Comment: @BigDong It doesn't unless you tell it to. If you want to run an image that's not based on docker image you have to add it.

Comment: how do I determine the hostname then ? I think I can't just write `docker` as the ip am I correct?

Comment: @BigDong Yes. I should probably give a complete example.