# Is there a `ssh-add` Linux alpine one liner

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sh

I need during a Gitlab-CI build to authenticate with ssh-agent from an alpine image.

I am looking for a **sh** one liner equivalent of this **bash** command [(picked from the gitlab documentation)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor):

```
ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

I have tried :

```
echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY | ssh-add -
Enter passphrase for (stdin): ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

printf '%s\n' "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Incidentally, this is [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to quote the variable in your first command:

```
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
     ^----------------^
```

Or specify `-` as the filename in your second command:

```
printf '%s\n' "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
                                      -----^
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean "and", rather than "or"? (The latter isn't a substitute for the former, after all).

Comment: Yes, the correct answer should be `echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" || ssh-add -`

Comment: I think `|` in this context (bash oneliner) is a pipe, not a logical AND or OR. 
There's a different issue with that solution. ssh-add will open a dialog and ask for passphrase and wait for input. I've seen solutions to that using expect.

Comment: hmm, I am getting `-: No such file or directory` in that example (running inside a docker container).

Comment: Make sure you start an SSH agent first with `eval $(ssh-agent)`. Other solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: @JoshM. right - worth mention that this works only on bash - but your link contains other solutions too.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this command:

```
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
```